# jQuery UI Autocomplete input value substring

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery UI Autocomplete.
I want substring text in input box when value is very long.

For example

`var availableTags = [
        "value long long long long",
        "value"
    ];`

```
$( ".chooseGiftWrapper input#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    minLength: 0,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $('.ui-menu').width(200).css({'position':'static','top': '0'});
        $('#chooseGiftWrapperHead .listFriends').show().addClass('open');
        nameFriendPosition();
         $('.listFriendsWrapper.scroll').jScrollPane({autoReinitialise: true});
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {

        $('#chooseGiftWrapperHead .chooseGiftcloseBtn').addClass('active');
        $('.dropDownBlock.listFriends').hide().removeClass('open');

    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        var default_value = $(this).attr('default_value');
        if ($(this).val() == default_value) {
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).removeClass('set_default');
            $('#chooseGiftWrapperHead .chooseGiftcloseBtn').removeClass('active');
        } 


    },
    change: function(event, ui) {

    }
})
.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li />")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a><img src='img/testAvatar.png'><p class='nameFriend'>" + item.label + "</p></a>")                                
        .appendTo(ul);
}
```

But select event doesn't work for me.

Comment: There could be multiple places in this code that you're getting an exception. Try placing some console.log('debug1') in your code so you can see where you're getting to. Could you past more of your code?

Comment: pls add your html snippet also

Comment: shouldnot you add more logic into your select event function? 
``if(availableTags[0].length>25){ take availableTags[1]}``

Comment: I found a solution to the problem

select: function(event, ui) {
   name = ui.item.value;
   lengthName = name.length;
   substrName = '';
   if( lengthName > 23){
    ui.item.value = name.substr(0,23) + '...';
   } else {
    ui.item.value = name;
   }
   $(this).val(ui.item.value);
   
   
   $('#chooseGiftWrapperHead .chooseGiftcloseBtn').addClass('active');
   $('.dropDownBlock.listFriends').hide().removeClass('open');
   
  },

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the problem

```
select: function(event, ui) {
            name = ui.item.value;
            lengthName = name.length;
            substrName = '';
            if( lengthName > 23){
                ui.item.value = name.substr(0,23) + '...';
            } else {
                ui.item.value = name;
            }
            $(this).val(ui.item.value);


            $('#chooseGiftWrapperHead .chooseGiftcloseBtn').addClass('active');
            $('.dropDownBlock.listFriends').hide().removeClass('open');

        },
```